# Analyzing MSIL code generated from C#

Tags: c#, il

I have the following function:

```
public string MyPhrase(int val)
{
    if ((val %3 == 0) && (val % 6 == 0))
        return "Fizz Bang";
    if (val % 3 == 0)
        return "Fizz";
    if (val % 6 == 0)
        return "Bang";
    return "";
}
```

After compiling this and viewing it with IlDasm, I get this output:

```
IL_0000:  ldarg.1
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.3
IL_0002:  rem
IL_0003:  brtrue.s   IL_0010

IL_0005:  ldarg.1
IL_0006:  ldc.i4.6
IL_0007:  rem
IL_0008:  brtrue.s   IL_0010

IL_000a:  ldstr      "Fizz Bang"
IL_000f:  ret

IL_0010:  ldarg.1
IL_0011:  ldc.i4.3
IL_0012:  rem
IL_0013:  brtrue.s   IL_001b

IL_0015:  ldstr      "Fizz"
IL_001a:  ret

IL_001b:  ldarg.1
IL_001c:  ldc.i4.6
IL_001d:  rem
IL_001e:  brtrue.s   IL_0026

IL_0020:  ldstr      "Bang"
IL_0025:  ret

IL_0026:  ldstr      ""
IL_002b:  ret
```

From looking at [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.brtrue%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), `brtrue` will branch if true. What's confusing me is the line `IL_0003`. Its saying that it should branch to line `IL_0010` if its true. In my C# code though, I am using an `&&` to compare two expressions before my program flow should jump to the next `if`. It seems backwards. From the MSIL code posted, it seems like its checking to see if my operation is true and if it is, its jumping to my next `if` block, which would be logically wrong. Can someone explain what I'm missing?

Comment: I wonder why you chose this example. Not that the compiler figures this out, but `"Bang"` could never be returned, could it? If `val` were divisible by `6`, surely it would be divisible by `3` as well?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Indeed. That is why traditionally the FizzBang problem uses 3 and 5, not 3 and 6.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen - The actual function isn't useful at all. I was just analyzing some MSIL code for fun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a side-effect of *short circuit evaluation* for the && operator.  Which promises that the right-hand expression of the operator does not get evaluated if the left-hand side is false.  So you see it skip the val % 6 == 0 expression and the return "Fizz Bang" statement if the REM opcode returns a non-zero result.

Comment: Yes, "true" means "non-zero" in this world, and OP compares with `0`.

Answer (score 1):

**brtrue.s** transfers control to the given target if the value on the stack is non-zero.

so, In your IL code `IL_0003` is tranfers control to `IL_0010`. means (val % 3 == 0) condition return false. you used `&&` in first if condition `if ((val %3 == 0) && (val % 6 == 0))` so, on first condition `(val % 3 == 0)`  return false, second condition will not check

```
IL_0005:  ldarg.1
IL_0006:  ldc.i4.6
IL_0007:  rem
IL_0008:  brtrue.s   IL_0010
```

and control transfer to `IL_0010`

```
IL_0010:  ldarg.1
IL_0011:  ldc.i4.3
IL_0012:  rem
IL_0013:  brtrue.s   IL_001b
```

check out this for more information: http://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/archive/2004/09/23/introduction-to-msil-part-6-common-language-constructs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This blok load arguments data from Stack, before begin comparing

So it's normal to jump to this section of loading data

```
IL_0010:  ldarg.1
IL_0011:  ldc.i4.3
...
```